# moving through tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with start and end dates of training courses for candidates and need to move through the table checking that a candidates previous records end date is not before their current records start date.

in other words I need to check that a candidates training records do not overlap and if they do I need to be able to send the bad records to another table.

I've added an example here where all the dates are incorrect as all the end dates are after the next records start date.

I've tried while loops and cursors but I can't see a way to store a value from one record while moving on to the next in order to compare it.
thanks.

```
PERS_ID PERS_TYPE_SD    PERS_TYPE_ED
6444    2006-08-01 00:00:00.000 2018-07-29 00:00:00.000
6444    2009-08-01 00:00:00.000 2012-07-31 00:00:00.000
6444    2007-08-01 00:00:00.000 2009-07-31 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from table as t1 
join table as t2 
  on t2.PERS_TYPE_SD > t1.PERS_TYPE_SD 
 and t2.PERS_TYPE_SD < t1.PERS_TYPE_ED 
 and t1.PERS_ID < t2.PERS_ID  
order by  t1.PERS_ID, t2.PERS_ID
```

Comment: @JulesII: Note the use of a self-join in the solution above, in place of a cursor. Understanding techniques such as this are the core concept in understanding how to leverage the true power of SQL. If you wish to truly become competent at SQL, banish all thoughts of cursors and "moving through tables" from your vocabulary, and even your dreams and nightmares.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Notice the protocol of SO and +1 an answer you respect.  Really if the only purpose of your comment was to admonish the OP then comment on the question not the answer.

Comment: Your answer is useful, so I have raised it; thank you for noting my careless oversight. However the purpose of my comment was to extend your answer to assist the OP in advancing in SQL knowledge. Rightly or wrongly I did not feel comfortable making such an addition to your answer as an edit. If you find any portion of my comment valuable, feel free to incorporate it in yourself, or not.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Cool, but telling the user not to use a cursor when the posted answer is set based is kind of redundant. But if they knew the difference they would not have asked the question in the first place.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Thanks very much for your answer and assistance.  If I may, there is an additional issue that I was not made aware of until this morning.  This test needs to be set up prior to a record being added.  in other words on an input screen a user adds a start and end date and I have to check if the given dates as input variables are already within the dates already in the table for that user.  so if a start date of 1/08/2008 and end date of 1/10/2008 were tried and a start date of 1/7/2007 to 1/12 2009 was already in use this would show an error message.

Comment: Welcome to SO. PieterGeerkens did not answer the question.  Come on you could not figure out select count from table where PERS_TYPE_SD < date and PERS_TYPE_ED < date and PERS_ID = id?  If you have a new question then enter a new question.  If this is an answer to the stated question then click the check.